# unity-socket io error right after import

Tags: c#, socket.io, unity-game-engine

**Hi**

first sorry for my poor English.

i am in the start point of learning build multiplayer games with unity(5.3.4p3), node.sj and socket.io package(Version: 1.0.2 (Sep 24, 2014)).

I downloaded it from unity asset store from within unity. And import whole package.

3 **Errors** occurred without any changes from me:

**1)**Assets/SocketIO/WebsocketSharp/Ext.cs(84,81): error CS1729 : The Type 'System.IO.Compression.Deflatestream does not contain a constructor that takes '3' arguments

**2)**is the same error in (118,83)

**3)**Assets/SocketIO/WebsocketSharp/Net/HttpConnection.cs(96,16): error CS1061Ttype 'WebSocketSharp.Net.Security.SslSteram' does not contain a definition for 'AuthenticateAsSrver' and no extension method 'AutenthenteAsServer' of type 'WebSocketSharp.Net.Security.SslStream' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly refrence?)

(notice that there is 2 warning that is not the problem. the problem is these 3 errors that i can't play a check my game without fix them.)

for the 1 and 2 , I check the Ext.cs script file. and it seems the function have 2 constructor that one of them have 3 argument. **it seems normal. but error says otherwise!!** ;

**here is the line:**

using (var ds = new DeflateStream (output, CompressionMode.Compress, true)) {

**and the whole part:**

```
private static MemoryStream compress (this Stream stream)
{
  var output = new MemoryStream ();
  if (stream.Length == 0)
    return output;

  stream.Position = 0;
  using (var ds = new DeflateStream (output, CompressionMode.Compress, true)) {
    stream.CopyTo (ds);
    ds.Close (); // "BFINAL" set to 1.
    output.Position = 0;

    return output;
  }
}
```

i tried to delete Third argument ( "true". a bool value).changing it to 2 argument form. the error gone. but One another error appears in EndPointListener.cs .I think useless and will make more errors.

for error 3 , it seems that 'AutenticationAsServer' exists and is normal ...but again the error message says otherwise.

**the error line is :**

```
   sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer (listener.Certificate);
```

**And the function:**

```
public HttpConnection (Socket socket, EndPointListener listener)
{
  _socket = socket;
  _listener = listener;
  _secure = listener.IsSecure;

  var netStream = new NetworkStream (socket, false);
  if (_secure) {
    var sslStream = new SslStream (netStream, false);
    sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer (listener.Certificate);
    _stream = sslStream;
  }
  else {
    _stream = netStream;
  }

  _sync = new object ();
  _timeout = 90000; // 90k ms for first request, 15k ms from then on.
  _timer = new Timer (onTimeout, this, Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);

  init ();
}
```

it is the first function of HttpConnection.cs

i tried to comment this line .and the error gone ... but it may have consequences.

I don't know what wrong .. **please help if you can ...**

Comment: the only way that i could solve it is to download another unity version ... and no problem ... it seems some versions of unity have problems with socket.io packege

Answer (score 0):

Did you make other class named "socket" or else? Check if there is other class you made which you named same in the library.